# how to change filpped page background color in harism page curl

Tags: android, page-curl

I am developing a demo using harism page curl https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl . Now I want to change the white color which is visible when I curl a page, means white color which is at back side of each page. Can anybody tell me how can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use like dat........

```
    mAnimationHandler = new FlipAnimationHandler();

    // Create our edge paint
    mCurlEdgePaint = new Paint();
    mCurlEdgePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setShadowLayer(10, -5, 5, 0x99000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
page.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 190, 150), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
```